# How do you increase the opaqueness of a child element with opacity in HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do I set the opacity of a child element back to `initial` or `1.0` after the parent element's opacity is reduced? The child remains transparent.

```css
.user-edit2 {
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}

.card {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #666;
  opacity: 1.0;
  color: white;
}

.form-control:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="user-edit2">
  <h2>Member Profile</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Personal Details</div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <br>
  <p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Save"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried

```
.card {
  /*opacity: 0.6;*/
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

base on [Opacity bleeding into child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929936/opacity-bleeding-into-child-divs), but it still didn't work.

Chrome Browser

Comment: Note that your html is incorrect, you are closing one more div that than you should. Had to recheck this statement because the indentation didn't help lol.

Comment: You can checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879045/how-to-set-opacity-in-parent-div-and-not-affect-in-child-div) thread, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't. The opacity of an element affects how all its child elements are rendered. Here's an approximation of the look using some background-color overrides and opacity changes only for *sibling* elements. Take note of the places where I had to use `!important`. Bootstrap (or other styles being included here) has some declarations that are more specific; you may be able to just write better selectors based on the context you're using this in.

```css
.user-edit2 {
  /* for solid colors, you can use rgba to simulate transparency without affecting contents */
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6) !important;
}

.user-edit2 .card-header,
.user-edit2 .card {
  /* these have background-colors declared somewhere else, so... */
  background: transparent !important;
}

/* You could also use an rgba value for color here,
or a non-transparent color that's a mix of black and red. Did this cause it's fast. */
.user-edit2 .card-header,
.user-edit2 h2 {
opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Note - these styles aren't being applied. Not specific enough maybe? Try scoping them as seen above. */
.form-control {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="user-edit2">
  <h2>Member Profile</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Personal Details</div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-text">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control" type="text"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Save"></p>
</form>
</div>
```